# struct alignment on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c, 64-bit, alignment

I have the following struct on a 64-bit Linux machine.

```
struct __wait_queue_head {
          spinlock_t lock;
          struct list_head task_list;
  };

where

typedef struct {
          raw_spinlock_t raw_lock;
  } spinlock_t;

and

struct list_head {
          struct list_head *next, *prev;
  };

raw_spinlock_t is defined as:

typedef struct {
          volatile unsigned int slock;
  } raw_spinlock_t;
```

Now I want to understand the alignment of the struct __wait_queue_head on a 64-bit Linux machine following the LP64 standard. From what I know, since the first field of this struct ie.

```
spinlock_t lock
```

is an unsigned int, which occupies 4 bytes on a 64-bit machine, this struct should begin at a 4-byte aligned address. However, I have seen that is not the case on a real system. Instead, the struct begins at an 8 byte aligned address, although the alignment requirement of the first field would have been met by a 4 byte aligned address. Basically, what governs alignment of a struct? Please note that I am clear about the padding concept of fields within a struct. The alignment requirement of a struct itself is what I am finding confusing.

Comment: If I get you right, would it be that the compiler position each field on an 8byte alignment for performance improvement? registers are 64b so they could be loaded in one go..

Comment: Not every field is 8 byte aligned. Data types like unsigned short are 2 byte aligned and unsigned int is 4 byte aligned. For variables 'outside' a struct, the variable is expected to get aligned at 'sizeof(variable)' byte aligned address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alignment requirement of a struct is the biggest alignment requirement of any of its members. In this case, since `struct list_head` contains pointers, the alignment of `struct list_head` is 8 bytes. And since `struct __wait_queue_head` contains a `struct list_head`, its alignment is 8 bytes as well. This is required because if the struct had a looser alignment requirement, then the struct padding wouldn't be enough to guarantee that the members would be properly aligned.

Comment: Could you give an example of how struct padding won't be good enough to correctly align all the data members of the struct? IMO, padding would always be enough to correctly align the data members.

Comment: @Gaurav Imagine a struct that has a 4-byte member followed by an 8-byte member. The padding rules will add 4 bytes of padding between the members. If the struct is 8-byte aligned then both members will be 8-byte aligned, which is sufficient. If the struct is aligned to an *odd* multiple of 4 bytes, then the first member will be 4-byte aligned, but the second member will be misaligned because of the padding. The only way to get alignment right while giving *all* instances of the struct the same memory layout is to align according to the largest type.

Comment: Excuse me for still not getting this; but even if a struct is aligned to an odd multiple of 4 bytes say, 12 bytes, then why would we need padding in the first place? The first field would occupy 4 bytes, and then the next field could start at 16th byte, which is a perfect 8 byte aligned address. The alignment is still right for the data members. Please correct me if and where am I wrong.

Comment: @gjain assume that `struct x {int y; long z;};` is 12-byte aligned, without padding, `(int)&((struct x *)0)->z` is 4, which is misaligned